# Nancy authentication session timeout

Tags: session, timeout, nancy

I am using Nancy.Authentication.Forms. The users are vociferously complaining that their sessions are timing out too quickly (less than 5 minutes). I've searched high and low but cannot find how to set the session timeout time to one hour. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Thanks,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure what could be causing it because of the little information provided. But I think your problem is probably due to the encryption/decryption of the cookie.

**Cookie Encryption differs on application startup**

By default, a new key is created every time you start the application, which would cause decryption of the cookie to fail, causing authentication to fail, and requiring you to re-authenticate to create a new cookie.

By setting your own keys, every after restart the decryption will always be the same. This is VERY important if you have a load balancer.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/wiki/Forms-Authentication#a-word-on-cryptography

Answer (score 0):

Since I also did not find an answer, I would like to post my research result:

WithCookie accepts an expiration DateTime.

https://github.com/NancyFx/Nancy/blob/a9989a68db1c822d897932b2af5689284fe2ceb8/src/Nancy/ResponseExtensions.cs

```
public static Response WithCookie(this Response response, string name, string value, DateTime? expires);
```

In my case it would be:

```
return Response.AsRedirect(redirectUrl)
               .WithCookie(SecurityExtensions.CookieName,  newSession.Id.ToString(), DateTime.Now.AddHours(1));
```

For the session duration itself I didn't find anything yet.